# What assembly language is this?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, gdb

What assembly language is this?

```
(gdb) disass bar
Dump of assembler code for function bar:
0x08048374 <bar+0>:  push   %ebp
0x08048375 <bar+1>:  mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048377 <bar+3>:  sub    $0x10,%esp
0x0804837a <bar+6>:  mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x0804837d <bar+9>:  add    $0x1,%eax
0x08048380 <bar+12>: mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
0x08048383 <bar+15>: mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
0x08048386 <bar+18>: leave  
0x08048387 <bar+19>: ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

Comment: If you could run GDB on it, why couldn't you run `file` on it and have the system tell you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's clearly 32-bit x86 assembly in [AT&T syntax](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm).